# Create Scroll Plot in PyQt for show long sample

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt, axes

I have a variabile with len=11.600. I want plot this data in a PyQt GUI, so I create an application with a widget and some PushButton. I create a matplotlibwidget with canvas. Everything is run! I can create a plot an see my data. The problem is: now, my x-axes is long about 11.600. I want just see a little window of the data and, using a navigation toolbar, I want scroll plot. How can I do this? Thank you